# Event for VideoView playback state or MediaController play/pause

Tags: android, playback, mediacontroller

I cant seem to find an event that listens for playback state. I am mostly interested in the `play/pause` state. I am using `MediaController` which has a `Play/Pause` button, but I have a secondary button that also controls `Play/Pause`. Using my custom button, I can `play/pause`, but if I `play/pause` using the `MediaController` `play/pause` button, I currently have no way to change the image on my custom `play/pause` button to either play or pause.

Is there an event that I do not know about so I can do some work during play/pause?

This is a very similar question: [How to catch event when click pause/play button on MediaController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868191/how-to-catch-event-when-click-pause-play-button-on-mediacontroller)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

If you're using the `MediaController` in combination with a `VideoView`, it should be relatively easy to extend the latter and add your own listener to it.

The custom VideoView would then look something like this in its most basic form:

```
public class CustomVideoView extends VideoView {

    private PlayPauseListener mListener;

    public CustomVideoView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setPlayPauseListener(PlayPauseListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        super.pause();
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onPause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onPlay();
        }
    }

    public static interface PlayPauseListener {
        void onPlay();
        void onPause();
    }

}
```

Using it is identical to using a regular `VideoView`, with the only difference being that we can now hook up our own listener to it.

```
// Some other code above...
CustomVideoView cVideoView = (CustomVideoView) findViewById(R.id.custom_videoview);
cVideoView.setPlayPauseListener(new CustomVideoView.PlayPauseListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPlay() {
        System.out.println("Play!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        System.out.println("Pause!");
    }
});

cVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
cVideoView.setVideoURI(...);
// or
cVideoView.setVideoPath(...);
// Some other code below...
```

Finally, you may also declare it in your xml layout and inflate it (as shown above) - just make sure your use `<package_name>.CustomVideoView`. Example:

```
<mh.so.CustomVideoView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/custom_videoview" />
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you sir, that worked perfectly. +50 to you. I can't wait until I know java as well as I know other things like action script.

Comment: Glad to have been of help. :) By the way, a call to `super` is usually done in conjunction with overriding a method. By overriding you're basically redefining the base/super/parent class's method. If you call `super` in such an overridden method you will retain it's functionality, which is what you want to do if your goal is to *add* functionality. Sometimes you may want to *replace* functionality though, in which case you may get the desired outcome by not calling `super`.

Comment: @MH. Can we get the buffering state, means the video view working fine but due to poor/slow internet connection it stop in middle as buffering and play again and so on. So how can we analyse that state so that I can set wait/buffer progress bar.

Comment: @Sadiq: Unfortunately `VideoView` doesn't offer any callbacks to get buffering updates. However, you can try getting a reference to the underlying `MediaPlayer` instance in the `OnPreparedListener` callback and setting a `OnBufferingUpdateListener` to that. Note that this will override the `VideoView`s listener, but that shouldn't be a big deal as the latter only uses it to keep track of the buffering percentage (but doesn't use it anywhere, except for returning it in `getBufferPercentage()`).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set your own [MediaController.MediaPlayerControl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.MediaPlayerControl.html) and override pause and start

Comment: if I `@Override` the pause() start() methods, how can I do like a dispatchEvent method (dispatchEvent is an actionscript method) that I can listen to on my custom MediaController. Also, I still want all the regular behaviors of pause and start, do I use `super` in that case? Never really understood super